# SWT: Convert keycode to string

Tags: java, swt

I'm writing a text widget in Java SWT that displays a user-defined keyboard shortcut, such as CTRL + A. Is there some way to map SWT's internal stateMask-keyCode pairs to a string, or do I have to do this by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See org.eclipse.jface.bindings.keys.KeySequenceText and org.eclipse.jface.bindings.keys.KeySequence for a similar usage.

Answer (score 0):

org.eclipse.jface.bindings.keys.SWTKeyLookup would help for simple string [Upper Case] to SWT keycode mapping